# How to join two dataframes columnwise?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2` containing an equal number of columns. I want to create another dataframe `df` by joining `df1` and `df2`.

The resulting dataframe should be formed by selecting `column1` from `df1` and `column1` from `df2` and join them together. Similarly `column2` from `df1` and `column2` from `df2` and so on.

Comment: The pandas documentation is very good. May I recommend doing a bit more online research first; then asking a code-specific question when you’re truly stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You can replace 'Column 1' and 'Column 2' with whatever name is required in your context.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Column 1','Column 2'], how = 'outer')
```